Se puede aislar el total de un Mesure en Power BI?
Tengo una representacion muy basica sobre algunos datos para calcular indices, al momento de sumar los datos en Power BI, obtengo un total (que son dependientes de algunos filtros), pero para el calculo que requiero necesito aislar los totales de las diferentes paginas del reporte y quiero saber si se puede lograr de alguna manera o simplemente la herramienta no puede hacer algo asi


te recomiendo hacer el [tour]

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
